# Python programming and group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, grouping

I have very long table, here is an example:

[image: 1]

and what do I want is to plot according to image number. given as 1,2,3 and scatter x y (given in column 2 and 3) coordinates on the plot. and color should be according to Type like **Green** for P and red for **F** and so on.

Plus I want them to plot separately not in the graph and save them like image.1 image2 and image 3.

Please suggest a possible solution.

I did grouping and now I'm stuck here.

I did until now is following:

```
for index, group in data.groupby(['image number']):
    
    group.plot(x='x',y='y', label=index, kind='scatter')
```

Please help me to add colors in the plot according to MP column.

[image: 2]

Comment: Please provide your data as text, and ideally a schematic of the expected graph

Comment: just want to scatter X and Y for every image number 1 2 3 and colour them according to MP.

Comment: What does "what do I want is to plot according to num. given as 1,2,3 and scatter x y corrdinates on the plot" even mean?

Comment: Dear;I have edited the question, please have a look now. I have 3 columns as Image number, X,Y and MP. Now I want to plot them on 3 different plots

Comment: what is MP exactly? The colour? What exactly do strings like "PMMA" correspond to? A list of colour codes or a look-up table would be nice.

Comment: Hi Lucas; pMMA and all are type of partciles and I want to assisgn them a color , like in the graph of image number 1 it should be  PP present only so pink color may be, you are right like a lookup table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I understand, your `dataframe` looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"number": 1, "x": 2391, "y": 1994, "MP": "PP"},
    {"number": 1, "x": 530, "y": 2707, "MP": "PP"},
    {"number": 1, "x": 467, "y": 3208, "MP": "PP"},
    {"number": 2, "x": 952, "y": 656, "MP": "PE"},
    {"number": 2, "x": 3678, "y": 1409, "MP": "PE"},
    {"number": 3, "x": 2950, "y": 177, "MP": "PMMA"},
    {"number": 3, "x": 1039, "y": 306, "MP": "f"},
    {"number": 3, "x": 2726, "y": 1827, "MP": "PMMA"},
    {"number": 3, "x": 3578, "y": 2129, "MP": "PMMA"},
    {"number": 3, "x": 3708, "y": 3624, "MP": "f"},
    # rest of dataframe entries...
    ])
```

If you want to make a scatter plot of these using `matplotlib`, you can just iterate over the dataframe and use `plt.scatter` to plot individual particles like so:

```
scheme = {
    "PP": "m", # PP is magenta
    "PE": "g", # PE is green
    "PMMA": "c", # PMMA is cyan
    "f": "r", # f is red
    # put more colours here...
    }

def plot_single(df, num, scheme):
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df["number"][i] == num:
            plt.scatter(x=df["x"][i], y=df["y"][i], c = scheme[df["MP"][i]] if df["MP"][i] in scheme else "k")
    # V change these as needed V
    plt.title("Particle "+str(num))
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    # ^ change these as needed ^
    plt.show()
```

As an example, if you try `plot_single(df, 1, scheme)` with the small snippet of the `dataframe`, you will get this graph:

[image: Image1.png]

To further customize your scatter plot, you can add a [legend](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), change the [colour scheme](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html), tinker with the [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html), etc.

EDIT:

if you want all the scatter plots on one graph, you can do it with a function like so:

```
def plot_all(df, scheme):
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        plt.scatter(x=df["x"][i], y=df["y"][i], c = scheme[df["MP"][i]] if df["MP"][i] in scheme else "k")
    plt.title("All Particles")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.show()
```

And you can call it by typing `plot_all(df, scheme)` into your shell.

Comment: Thanks Luca, as it worked for one after  command *plot_single(df, 1, scheme)*, isnt it possible if it can work for all others using for loop on its own I mean for 1 2 3 .....

Comment: I just added an edit to my answer addressing your follow up. If you want to automatically generate each individual graph one after the other, you can use a loop to call the `plot_single` function several times, i.e. `for i in range(3): plot_single(df, i+1, scheme)`